# (De-)Serialize Bean in a custom way at runtime

Tags: java, json, jackson

Let's imagine I have the following POJO:

```
class Pojo {
    String s;
    Object o;
    Map<String, String> m;
}
```

And at runtime, I want default serialization / deserialization for all properties except one. Typically, I want to replace a field by its ID in a database when serializing, similarly to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325096/deserializing-entities-with-relationships).

For example, I want to replace `o` by a string obtained from an external mapping (for example: `object1` <=> "123" and `object2` <=> "456"):

- serialization: read `o` and replace (so if `o` is `object1`, serialize as string "123")
- deserialization: read "123", query some table to get the original value of `o` back (i.e. `object1`), recreate a `Pojo` object with `o = object1`.

I understand that Modules would be one way to do that but I'm not sure how to use them while keeping the automatic BeanSerializer/Deserializer for the properties that don't need to be changed.

Can someone give an example (even contrived) or an alternative approach?

---

Notes:

- I can't use annotations or Mixins as the changes are unknown at compile time (i.e. any properties might be changed in a way that is not determinable).
- [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981359/jackson-suppressing-serializationwrite-of-properties-dynamically) points to using a CustomSerializerFactory, which seems to do the job. Unfortunately, the official site indicates that [it is not the recommended approach any more](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/CustomSerializerFactory) and that modules should be used instead.

---

**Edit**

To be a little clearer, I can do the following with Mixins for example:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(MongoBsonFactory.createFactory());
mapper.addMixInAnnotations(Pojo.class, PojoMixIn.class);

ObjectReader reader = mapper.reader(Pojo.class);
DBEncoder dbEncoder = DefaultDBEncoder.FACTORY.create();
OutputBuffer buffer = new BasicOutputBuffer();
dbEncoder.writeObject(buffer, o);
```

with the following Mixin:

```
abstract class PojoMixIn {
    @JsonIgnore Object o;
}
```

And then add the required string to the JSON content. But I would need to know at compile time that it is the `o` field that needs to be replaced, which I don't.

Comment: > I can't use annotations or Mixins as the changes are unknown at compile time (i.e. any properties might be    >changed in a way that is not determinable).                                                   Could you clarify, please?  Very confused, because everything above "Notes:" heading is static and known at compile time.  Are classes (Pojo) & fields of Pojo not known in advance?

Comment: Are you suggesting it's not safe to assume any class structure? Raw (untyped/simple) data binding deserialises object JSON structure as LinkedHashMap<String,Object>, and array JSON structure as ArrayList<Object>, and primitive JSON fields as java primitive wrappers.

Comment: @GlenBest Yes the Pojo class could be more or less anything. I gave an example where `o` is replaced by a String. But later on in the program, it might be `m` which needs to be replaced by some String and `o` serialized "normally".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think `@JsonSerialize` and `@JsonDeserialize` is what you need. These annotations give you control on the serialization/deserialization of particular fields. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921812/create-a-custom-jackson-annotation) shows elegant way to combine them into one annotation.

**UPD.** For this complex scenario you could take a look at `BeanSerializerModifier/BeanDeserializerModifier` classes. The idea is to modify general `BeanSerializer/BeanDeserializer` with your custom logic for particular fields and let basic implementation to do other stuff. Will post an example some time later.

**UPD2.** As I see, one of the way could be to use `changeProperties` method and assign your own serializer.

**UPD3.** Updated with working example of custom serializer. Deserialization could be done in similar way.

**UPD4.** Updated example with full custom serialization/deserialization. (I have used **jakson-mapper-asl-1.9.8**)

```
  public class TestBeanSerializationModifiers {

    static final String PropertyName = "customProperty";
    static final String CustomValue = "customValue";
    static final String BaseValue = "baseValue";

    // Custom serialization

    static class CustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
        @Override
        public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            String customValue = CustomValue; // someService.getCustomValue(value);
            jgen.writeString(customValue);
        }
    }

    static class MyBeanSerializerModifier extends BeanSerializerModifier {
        @Override
        public List<BeanPropertyWriter> changeProperties(SerializationConfig config, BasicBeanDescription beanDesc, List<BeanPropertyWriter> beanProperties) {
            for (int i = 0; i < beanProperties.size(); i++) {
                BeanPropertyWriter beanPropertyWriter = beanProperties.get(i);
                if (PropertyName.equals(beanPropertyWriter.getName())) {
                    beanProperties.set(i, beanPropertyWriter.withSerializer(new CustomSerializer()));
                }
            }
            return beanProperties;
        }
    }

    // Custom deserialization

    static class CustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Object> {
        @Override
        public Object deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            // serialized value, 'customValue'
            String serializedValue = jp.getText();
            String baseValue = BaseValue; // someService.restoreOldValue(serializedValue);
            return baseValue;
        }
    }

    static class MyBeanDeserializerModifier extends BeanDeserializerModifier {
        @Override
        public BeanDeserializerBuilder updateBuilder(DeserializationConfig config, BasicBeanDescription beanDesc, BeanDeserializerBuilder builder) {
            Iterator<SettableBeanProperty> beanPropertyIterator = builder.getProperties();
            while (beanPropertyIterator.hasNext()) {
                SettableBeanProperty settableBeanProperty = beanPropertyIterator.next();
                if (PropertyName.equals(settableBeanProperty.getName())) {
                    SettableBeanProperty newSettableBeanProperty = settableBeanProperty.withValueDeserializer(new CustomDeserializer());
                    builder.addOrReplaceProperty(newSettableBeanProperty, true);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return builder;
        }
    }

    static class Model {

        private String customProperty = BaseValue;
        private String[] someArray = new String[]{"one", "two"};

        public String getCustomProperty() {
            return customProperty;
        }

        public void setCustomProperty(String customProperty) {
            this.customProperty = customProperty;
        }

        public String[] getSomeArray() {
            return someArray;
        }

        public void setSomeArray(String[] someArray) {
            this.someArray = someArray;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SerializerFactory serializerFactory = BeanSerializerFactory
                .instance
                .withSerializerModifier(new MyBeanSerializerModifier());

        DeserializerFactory deserializerFactory = BeanDeserializerFactory
                .instance
                .withDeserializerModifier(new MyBeanDeserializerModifier());

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setSerializerFactory(serializerFactory);
        objectMapper.setDeserializerProvider(new StdDeserializerProvider(deserializerFactory));

        try {
            final String fileName = "test-serialization.json";
            // Store, "customValue" -> json
            objectMapper.writeValue(new File(fileName), new Model());
            // Restore, "baseValue" -> model
            Model model = objectMapper.readValue(new File(fileName), Model.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your update - [BeanPropertyWriter](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/BeanPropertyWriter.html) does not have a `withSerializer` method. Maybe you are using a different version?

Comment: `beanPropertyWriter.assignSerializer(new MyCustomSerializer());` did the trick.

Comment: Very nice - that does the trick. Can you also show how to deserialize back to a model object (by replacing customValue by baseValue)?

Comment: I have updated the answer, my version is 1.9.8, but I think for 2.1 it should be pretty similar.

Comment: beanProperties.set(i, beanPropertyWriter.assignSerializer(new CustomSerializer())); gives compilation error. AssignSerializer returns void

Comment: There is no longer a `setSerializerProvider()` method on `ObjectMapper`. The recommended way to achieve custom serialization is by utilising a `SimpleModule` on which you can call `setSerializerModifier()`/`setDeserializerModifier()` and then register it with the `ObjectMapper`.